# PreparedStatement.executeUpdate() is not working for Oracle

Tags: java

I am using `PreparedStatement` for executing the update query.
The following is the query:

```
String callersUpdateQuery = "update W67U999S a set pcrdattim= ? where exists (select b.CRDATTIM, b.RECORDCD, b.CRNODE, b.UNITCD, b.WRKTYPE from W03U999S b where a.PCRDATTIM = ? and a.CCRDATTIM = b.CRDATTIM and a.CRECORDCD = b.RECORDCD and a.CCRNODE = b.CRNODE and a.PRECORDCD = 'F' and a.PCRNODE = '01' and b.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER' and b.UNITCD=? and a.crecordcd='T')";
```

The below is the java code that should update the records:

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(callersUpdateQuery);
                preparedStatement.setString(1,newFolderCrdattim);  
                preparedStatement.setString(2,crdattim);  
                preparedStatement.setString(3,businessAreaName.trim());
                int j = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

But `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()` is not updating the required rows and returning the updated rows count as zero. Weirdly, the same sql query when I execute at the database end, the records are getting updated.
My database is Oracle  and the schema of the table that should be updated is below:

```
Name        Null     Type       
----------- -------- ---------- 
PCRDATTIM   NOT NULL CHAR(26)   
PRECORDCD   NOT NULL CHAR(1)    
PCRNODE     NOT NULL CHAR(2)    
RECORDTYPE  NOT NULL NUMBER(3)  
CCRDATTIM   NOT NULL CHAR(26)   
CRECORDCD   NOT NULL CHAR(1)    
CCRNODE     NOT NULL CHAR(2)    
CRDATTIM    NOT NULL CHAR(26)   
LINKRULE_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(14)
```

Can anyone guess what's wrong with the code or query?

Comment: *"Can anyone guess...?"* Sure, I'm *guessing* that it has something to do with the value of `crdattim` and/or `businessAreaName`.

Comment: *FYI:* Don't put conditions on `a` inside the `exists` clause. They should be outside as part of the `where` clause of the `update`.

Comment: What is the type and size of `b.UNITCD`?  Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894238/query-column-with-char-data-type-in-oracle) might help.

Comment: The type of `b.UNITCD` is `CHAR`. FYI, all are CHAR type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle `CHAR` type is the culprit here. The columns that I want to update are of type `CHAR`. That's causing the issue. This link helped me in figuring out the solution: [Oracle JDBC and Oracle CHAR data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332845/oracle-jdbc-and-oracle-char-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

First, did you check for existence of tuples on the select you're using as condition in where clause?

If there are rows being returned. The issue may be related to the transaction in which you're executing your update statement. Double check for your transaction mode and if it is really being committed.

As a query optimization suggestion I'd change the statement to:

```
String callersUpdateQuery = 
    "update W67U999S a 
     set pcrdattim= ? 
     where 
            a.PCRDATTIM = ? 
        and a.PRECORDCD = 'F' 
        and a.PCRNODE   = '01' 
        and a.CRECORDCD ='T'

        and exists (
            select 
                b.CRDATTIM, 
                b.RECORDCD, 
                b.CRNODE, 
                b.WRKTYPE 
            from W03U999S b 
            where 
                  b.CCRDATTIM = a.CRDATTIM 
              and b.CRECORDCD = a.RECORDCD 
              and b.CCRNODE = a.CRNODE 
              and b.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER' 
              and b.UNITCD=? 
        )";
```

That way you will be first reducing the tuples from `a` then use it to narrow the `b` tuples only to those that match.

Comment: The same query with same values is successfully executed via SQL editor. Does `exists` causing the issue here?

Comment: But inside SQL editor the auto commit function may be active. Committing your update automatically or the data you're viewing is visible to you because you're in the same transaction. If your program doesn't actively commit, your transaction is rolled back at the end of its execution.

Comment: Oracle CHAR type is the culprit here. The columns that I want to update are of type CHAR. That's causing the issue. This link helped me in figuring out the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332845/oracle-jdbc-and-oracle-char-data-type

Comment: Nice for the feedback! So, the SELECT statement wasn't working properly (somehow SQL editor is handling the trimming on the column). Moving the column from CHAR to VARCHAR would be the preferred solution.